# Show Message on Android App in Real time

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an application, where a random number is being generated in an android app, and after that, I am inserting that code in Web Base app.

What I am looking for is, when I am updating the value from web app to MySql database, I want at the same time, to show a message on android app that number has been saved, without doing any action in Android app.

```
signage-e36e0: null
```

I have tried Firebase, but I don't think Firebase would be needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can show a message in the app once the Webcall for sending rendom number is finished from app side you can know that event in HTTP Client you are using.
2. If it's not possible for you to listen to HTTP Response then You can utilize **Firebase Cloud messaging(FCM)** for this.
   When you change the value in the database you can send the message to the app via FCM and app will show a message on the screen based on that message.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/